# Flutter/Dart -- Found some good code to make an add two numbers calc, but i need to add 20 numbers together, ill show code and out put no real errors

Tags: flutter, class, state

The third target:3 does not add to target 1 and 2. Target 1 and Target 2 both add together corectly

Notice the "TextEditingController num3controller = new TextEditingController();" has been added by me to try to add 3 fields to add do i need to use a differnt class or syntax to add multiple fields thanks all

Pic attached of output
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZTnz.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKkpP.png)

Result

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appTitle = 'Twin City Bowmen Score Sheet';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(appTitle),
        ),
        body: AddTwoNumbers(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AddTwoNumbers extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddTwoNumbersState createState() => _AddTwoNumbersState();
}

class _AddTwoNumbersState extends State<AddTwoNumbers> {
  TextEditingController num1controller = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController num2controller = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController num3controller = new TextEditingController();
  String result = "0";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Target 1:"),
              new Flexible(
                child: new TextField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  controller: num1controller,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Target 2:"),
              new Flexible(
                child: new TextField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  controller: num2controller,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Target 3:"),
              new Flexible(
                child: new TextField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  controller: num3controller,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Text("Add"),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    int sum = int.parse(num1controller.text) +
                        int.parse(num2controller.text);
                    result = sum.toString();
                  });
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "Result:",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 30,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                result,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 30,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly this should be the solution:

```
setState(() {
                int sum = int.parse(num1controller.text) +
                    int.parse(num2controller.text) +
                    int.parse(num3controller.text);
                result = sum.toString();
              });
```

Comment: Thank Felix, newbie to Flutter, so you mean just add this code or replace wrong code i have added a pic of the wrong output thanks via emulator

Comment: Thank Felix adding 3 worked so i tried this for an example is this correct for adding more numbers:
                  setState(() {
                    int sum = int.parse(num1controller.text) +
                        int.parse(num2controller.text) +
                        int.parse(num3controller.text) +
                        int.parse(num4controller.text) +
                        int.parse(num5controller.text) +
                        int.parse(num6controller.text) +
                        int.parse(num7controller.text);
                    result = sum.toString();

Comment: If this is a problem for you I would recommend you to learn the basics of programming first. For this you should start with a simpler language than dart, for example python.

But if you add some extra TextInputs this is right :)

Comment: Sorry all good what you did worked thanks, im a Infrastructure engineer, but havent coded for 20 year, love your work thanks